# Unfamiliar Gradient Notation referencing first order Taylor approximation of f

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Below if my problem

## Gradient of some common functions.

Recall that the gradient of a differentiable function
$f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is defined as the vector
$$
\nabla f(x) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the partial derivatives are evaluated at the point $x$. The first order Taylor approximation of $f$, near $x$, is given by
$$
\hat{f}_{\!\mathrm{tay}}(z) 
= f(x) + \nabla f(x)^\top (z-x) 
$$

This function is affine, i.e., a linear function plus a constant. For $z$ near $x$, the Taylor approximation
$\hat{f}_{\!\mathrm{tay}}$ is very near $f$. Find the gradient of the following functions.
Express the gradients using matrix notation.

a) $f(x) = a^\top x + b$,
where $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

b) $f(x) = x^\top A\,x$,
for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

c) $f(x) = x^\top A\,x$,
where $A = A^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.
(Yes, this is a special case of the previous one.)

## My Issue

This is the starting framework shown to solve the above, but I am unfamiliar with this formula. It looks like a finite differentiation equation, but I don't know it with both the $h$ and the $\Delta x$. I'm also confused about the
$$
\frac{g^\top \Delta x}{\| \Delta x \|}
$$
expression. My guess is it is some reference to the Taylor approximation, but I'm struggling to connect the two. Any help would be great!

$$
\frac{g^\top \Delta x}{\|\Delta x\|} 
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h \Delta x) - f(x)}{\|h \Delta x\|}
$$

#### *Update*

I think I've gathered that $\Delta x$ is a vector of dimension (n x 1). Perhaps a vector of the change in $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$? But this still leads me with the question of what does $h$ represent? Some scalar that interacts with the vector $\Delta x$?

Answer (score 1):

I find the notation to be slightly confusing, but otherwise this is classic stuff in multivariable differential calculus.

Basically $\delta x$ is a fixed vector. It does not go to zero. It just tells you of a direction in which you want to find the variation of your function.

Now $h$ is a dummy parameter that dictates how far in this direction you go to compute the variation of the function. Now you bring this to zero and it gives you a quantity which is some kind of derivative, and which I'd like to call the **directional derivative in the direction $\delta x$**.

Now you can do that for any direction (imagine you're on a mountainside, if you go west you go up with a 3% slope, if you go north you go up with a 4% slope (east and south are the same but down), if you go northwest it's a different slope, etc...)

So each direction gives you a different directional derivative. Now you as long as this function is differentiable, then you have a magic vector call the gradient, which allows you to find any directional derivative by simply taking the dot product of the gradient with the directional vector $\delta x$.

Comment: Thank you @justt for the answer. That does make sense that delta x is a directional vector now that you explain it. Additional question: is delta x comprised of the basis vector of the direction of interest? or is it a "compound" vector that is in just any direction, not just the basis direction?

Comment: do you have any recommendation of textbook to point me towards to continue learning about this?

Comment: $\Delta_x$ is not necessarily a basis vector. Indeed the definition of the gradient tells you that this works obviously for basis vectors, but if your function is differentiable then then much more is true because your function is locally approximated by a linear map (that linear map is the dot product with the gradient)

Comment: You should look for textbooks about differential calculus and multivariable calculus. I learned that in french books so no specific recommendation that I can give, it's basic stuff in these topics so any book would contain it, for instance, see chapter 4 of that one I just found on the web: https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/780